# How to use a clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN by preventing two points to be in one cluster if their distance in one dimension exceeds threshold?

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, scipy, cluster-analysis

I try to cluster a large dataset having the columns time, xCoordinate and yCoordinate.
I want my final clusters to have two properties:

1. When two points are too far away from each other time wise (f.e. > 10 time periods between them) I don't want them to be in the same cluster.
2. Apart from the time restriction (1.), I want to apply normal clustering using the geographical values: so if I use f.e. DBSCAN I would define an appropriate epsilon value which is used for clustering on the geographical values.

My approach so far was to first compute two distance vectors, one using only the time value and one using only the geographical values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

arr = np.array([[0,1,1], [0,3,3], [0,1,2],...]) #array has dimensions [time,x,y]
n,m = arr.shape

time_dist = pdist(arr[:, 0].reshape(n, 1), metric='euclidean')
euc_dist = pdist(arr[:, 1:], metric='euclidean')
```

Then I filtered out all data points which have a higher time distance than the specified threshold value (f.e. 10) and set their geographical distance to 2*epsilon, to avoid them being in one cluster later on:

```
dist = np.where(time_dist <= 10, euc_dist, 2 * epsilon)  #filter the pairs with time difference > 10
```

Finally I built a square matrix of the distance vector and have it as an input to a clustering algorithm from sklearn.cluster, for example DBSCAN:

```
X = squareform(dist)
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3).fit(X)
```

This last step is a problem, since the building of a square distance matrix uses lots of memory space for a large number of data points and thus decreases performance a lot.
Since the only two possible input formats for the sklearn clustering algorithms (such as DBSCAN) are a precomputed distance matrix in square form as described above or a simple vector array of the data points (which I can't use since I want to implement the time restriction) I don't know how one can do the clustering more memory efficient.

Thanks a lot for any help / recommendations in advance!

Comment: I also can't think of a way to do it without building the distance matrix.  Using a sparse matrix might be helpful, depending on what your data looks like.  Stepping back from the implementation, I wonder if DBSCAN is going to produce some quirky results with distances constructed like this.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484099/do-k-means-dbscan-and-hierarchical-clustering-all-rely-on-pseudometrics...

Comment: ...and specifically, @Christian Hennig's comment there: *"the concept of a neighbourhood becomes weird if it is possible that... x and z both are in a close neighbourhood of y but are extremely far from each other."*  That's the situation you're going to have if, for example, x,y and z all have the same geographical location, but x is at t=0, y is at t=6 and z is at t=12.